# Evaluate solve_ivp solution on 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm solving an initial value problem with `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` with `dense_output=True`. This is supposed to yield an interpolating polynomial which can help me evaluate the solution at any arbitrary point within the domain of solution.

I want to evaluate the solution over a 2D array. I was expecting to be able to do it straightaway, but this does not seem possible:

```py
res = solve_ivp(... , dense_output = True)

res.sol(a_2d_array)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I can do it if I flatten the array first: `a_2d_array.ravel()`... but then I'd have to restore the shape again after evaluation. Is there a better (or more efficient) way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry for efficiency when you need to reshape arrays. They are fast because array data is not copied (normally).

Flatten:

```
>>> a = np.random.random((1000, 1000))
>>> shape = a.shape

>>> b = a.ravel()
>>> b.shape
(1000000,)
>>> b.base is a
True

>>> b = a.reshape(-1)
>>> b.shape
(1000000,)
>>> b.base is a
True
```

Recover the original shape:

```
>>> c = b.reshape(shape)
>>> c.shape
(1000, 1000)
>>> c.base is a
True

>>> b.shape = shape
>>> b.shape
(1000, 1000)
>>> b.base is a
True
```

Some timings:

```
>>> %timeit b = a.ravel()
128 ns ± 0.57 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> %timeit b = a.reshape(-1)
421 ns ± 59.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

>>> %timeit c = b.reshape(shape)
189 ns ± 1.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> %timeit b.shape = shape
152 ns ± 0.529 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have been using `ravel` + `reshape` so far without performance issues. It is interesting, though, that `reshape(-1)` takes ~3 times the time taken by `ravel`.